# How can I remove the "title" attribute from all links within a div?

Tags: javascript

So I have a div, `#footer-float`, for which I simply want to remove all of the "title" attributes automatically when the page loads, without editing the markup of the links themselves (they are automatically generated by MediaWiki). Basically the little tooltips are obtrusive and get in the way of reading what the links say.

I could do this easily enough with jQuery, I think, but would rather not load the whole library when this is likely all I'll use it for.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Questions type "Pleaze gimme teh codez" are not very welcome. Try first, if problems arise then ask question with code attached and jsFiddle example if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove all titles by looping through all link elements and setting the title to an empty string:

```
function onLoad() {
  var div = document.getElementById('footer-float');
  var links = div.getElementsByTagName('a');
  for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].title = '';
  }      
}
```

Comment: Both worked, since there were only li's and a's in the div. But this is a little more concise. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2):

This is a fairly straight-forward recursive function:

```
// Clear the "title" on all child elements.
function removeTitleOnChildren(node) {
    var child;

    for (child = node.firstChild; child; child = child.nextSibling) {
        if (child.nodeType === 1) { // Element
            if (child.nodeName === "A") { // An "a" element
                child.title = "";
            }
            removeTitleOnChildren(child);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
removeTitle(document.getElementById("footer-float"));
```

(The above assumes HTML, not XHTML; it matters for `nodeName`, which would be "a" in XHTML.)

Answer (score 0):

```
(function(){
    var links = document.getElementById("footer-float").getElementsByTagName("a");

for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
    links[i].removeAttribute("title");
}
    console.log(links);
})();
```

​

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/udyZa/6/

Comment: You're falling prey to *[The Horror of Implicit Globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html)* there... ;-)

Comment: So just put in inside a anonymous function then?

Comment: @ MaggiQall: Nope, `i` is *still* an implicit global.

Comment: Hey, I'm just trying to help. :-) Yup, that sorts it.